# How to make this jquery code fire the function itself instead of binding to a button to fire the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make this jquery code fire the function itself instead of binding to a button to fire the function?

```
self.ShowWindow= { observable: ko.observable(false) };
self.OnToggleShowWindow = (it) => () => it.observable(!it.observable());
$('#showWindowButton').click(self.OnToggleShowWindow (self.ShowWindow));
```

Right now I have to create a button and bind it with my code to be able to trigger a function in my react component. What I'm wondering is that, is it possible to just trigger the function without halving to trigger the jquery click?

My ViewModel in the javascript component.

```
$ViewModel = function (element) {
    var self = this;

    self.ShowWindow= { observable: ko.observable(false) };
    self.OnToggleShowWindow = (it) => () => it.observable(!it.observable());
    self.OnToggleShowWindow (self.ShowWindow);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        self.OnToggleShowWindow(self.ShowWindow)
    };

    self.ShowDialog = function (componentId, componentName) {
       // The fucntion OnToggleShowWindow is supposed to be called here
    };
}
```

Only outside the ShowDialog function is bound at rendering the page. After what the showdialog is just a function that updates on the already bounded observables.

In my react component I have subscribed to the function, which I now try to retrieve:

this.props.toggleShowWindow.observable.subscribe(this.onToggleShowWindow);

Comment: you could create a self calling function

Comment: what happens if you just call `self.OnToggleShowWindow (self.ShowWindow)`?

Comment: Nothing happens if I only  call self.OnToggleShowWindow (self.ShowWindow) in my function...

Comment: It seems like the viewmodel binds the observable OnToggleShowWindow, but when I use a function from the model like ShowDialog, which calls on self.OnToggleShowWindow (self.ShowWindow), nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `()` after it instead of passing it to `click`.

> ```
> $('#showWindowButton').click(self.OnToggleShowWindow (self.ShowWindow));
> ```

becomes:

```
self.OnToggleShowWindow(self.ShowWindow)()
```

---

Don't forget the `()` after it. Pay close attention to the above line of code and make sure you don't miss any `()` out.

Comment: I tried to call self.OnToggleShowWindow(self.ShowWindow)(); in showDialog and got this error:

self.OnToggleShowWindow

Comment: Sorry, the error is: caught TypeError: self.OnToggleShowWindow is not a function @Quentin

Comment: @Rest — If that was the case then the original code (`$('#showWindowButton').click(self.OnToggleShowWindow (self.ShowWindow));`) would also throw that error … unless you've thrown away previous line which defined that function in the first place.

Comment: @Quention it worked! :) 
Is it possible for me to write these three lines different? 

    self.ShowWindow= { observable: ko.observable(false) };
    self.OnToggleShowWindow = (it) => () => it.observable(!it.observable());
    self.OnToggleShowWindow (self.ShowWindow);

I mean do I need to write it like that, or could I write it in an easier way to understand?